# SQL via PDO and the use of transactions will not execute

Tags: php, transactions, pdo

I have been using PDO throughout my site; however, when it comes to updating a key in the auditkey table, the following (simplified method) will not successfully execute on the DB:

```
 try {
      $dbh = new PDO(etc...);
      $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      $currentKey = getCurrentKey(); //returns a SHA1 key
      beginTransaction($dbh); // not a typo, call to a wrapper function!
      $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE auditkey SET key=:nextKey");
      $stmt->bindValue(':nextKey', sha1($currentKey), PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $success = $stmt->execute();
      $dbh->commit();
    }
```

The error I get is the following:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to
>   use near
>   'key='f6aa38e947482563913c56c2c72a59ea623c7dfb''
>   at line 1

When the UPDATE is amended and entered manually, the SQL works fine:

```
UPDATE `auditkey` SET `key`='f6aa38e947482563913c56c2c72a59ea623c7dfb';
```

Comment: Something I learned recently, is that if you also have a `catch` function in  your script, after your `try`, which uses `$dbh->rollback()`, you must place `beginTransaction` outside of your `try`, otherwise your rollback doesn't have a point to roll back to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update query you posted at the end of your question is **not an equivalent** to the one you used in your prepared statement : in the hand-made query, the fields' names are enclosed in backticks.

This shouldn't change much for the `auditkey` field ; but it should change a lot for the `key` field, as **`key` is a reserved word**.

Try changing your prepared statement, to enclose the name of the `key` field in backticks :

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE auditkey SET `key`=:nextKey");
```

As a reference, here is the list of [**Reserved words**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) for MySQL.

Comment: Thanks, very much appreciate it! Wasn't exactly sure how/if PDO modified the SQL when preparing it database side. I've also amended the main post with regard to the "equivalent" SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You forget dolar symbol here:

```
  $beginTransaction($dbh);
```

Key is a reserved key word by MySQL.

Comment: Forgot to mention that it's a call to a wrapper function, amended main post